# Laravel: Cannot set locale in Mailable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, locale

I updated to Laravel 5.6 and I want to use the new `locale` method from a `Mailable` class.

I created a mailable class with

```
php artisan make:mail Test --markdown="emails.test"
```

This is my blade file:

```
@component('mail::message')
@lang('list.test')
@endcomponent
```

If I send a mail

```
  $test = new \App\Mail\Test();
  $test->locale('de');
  \Mail::to('myemail@test.com')->send($test);
```

Then the mail is not using my locale file from `resources/lang/de/list.php`

```
<?php 

   return [ 'test' => 'Dies ist ein Test'];
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use locale with Mail Facade.

```
$test = new \App\Mail\Test();
\Mail::to('myemail@test.com')->locale('de')->send($test);
```

Mail Facade and Mailable refers to different classes. for using `locale()` with Mailable try this.

```
 $test = new \App\Mail\Test();
 $test->locale('de')->send();
```

Comment: This works. But isn't locale a method on the `Mailable`object?

Comment: Just tested, it is still working. Now with Laravel 8.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the locale in to the constructor and setting then setting it in the `build` function:

```
public $locale;

public function __construct(string $locale = 'de')
{
    $this->locale = $locale;
}

public function build()
{
    return $this->locale($this->locale)
                ->from('example@example.com')
                ->view('emails.example');
}
```

Comment: Actually, this does not work. Configuring the `locale` in the builder is to late anyway, and setting it in the constructor will be overwritten by the `PendingMail` . I wrote a PR to fix it, see https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/29980#issuecomment-531266560

Comment: @Adam Still true, adding the locale to the build function did not work. Instead add the locale where you define the mailable.

Comment: @LesleyPeters I think Taylor fixed it by himself but never checked. Which versiona re you using?